# Proportion C.I confidence level with a change of variance

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, proportion, z-score

I recently learned about confidence interval for proportion now let's say i use a Z score and get the confidence interval of 95% as follows:
$$  C.I = \hat{p} \pm Z_{(1-0.95)/2} \sqrt{p(1-p)/n}
$$

now as i see it i have two options.

1. I can substitute p for p hat as it's an estimator for the proportion.
2. I can substitute p= 0.5 as it's the maximal variance i can get from a proportion estimate.

now the result of these is different, my question is which one of this ha a 95% confidence interval?  as  the confidence interval mostly determined my alpha and the variance has no relation to it. it's weird for me that changing the standard error does change the actual interval but not our confidence level.

Comment: First, all the p's in the formula should have hats.  Second, you cannot "substitute p for phat" I think you mean the opposite. But that's not necessary after you do the first thing. Third I don't know what Z score you are getting. The Z in the formula is one that you set. Finally (at least for now) the variance of a proportion is fixed by the proportion and the sample size; once you have estimated p, the variance of p is set.

Comment: @PeterFlom Your *"all the p's in the formula should have hats"* is not obviously correct:  If you had a small sample all negative then you might say $\hat p=0$ in this case but you should not be assuming the variance of $\hat p$ is $0$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval discusses this and various proposed approaches

Comment: @Henry That doesn't contradict what I said.  If you have a small sample, then the whole formula is inappropriate. But all the p's in that formula should be p hats, because you don't know p.

Comment: @PeterFlom and I am saying that if you use that expression and $\hat p$ in that standard error term, then your (Wald) confidence interval will often have a probability of covering the true value of $p$ of less than $95\%$ partly because $\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)/n}$ is a biased estimator of $\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$.  The $\hat p=0$ example is a extreme case of this.

Comment: @Henry I agree.  But, nonetheless, p (without a hat) does not belong in that formula. Getting a good CI for a proportion is trickier than many realize (as the Wikipedia artile points out), but that doesn't change my point.

Answer (score 0):

The best advice I could give you is to NOT use the proposed formula. The main reason is that its coverage will be erratic, and very often below your desired 95%.
Please read the wikipedia link provided by @Henry.
You should also consult the following paper:
Interval Estimation for a Binomial Proportion
Author(s): Lawrence D. Brown, T. Tony Cai and Anirban DasGupta
Source: Statistical Science , May, 2001, Vol. 16, No. 2 (May, 2001), pp. 101-117
It demonstrates how your formula (Wald interval) can mis-behave, and then shows how some alternate derivations behave better. Unfortunately that paper does not compare Wald to the "exact" binomial CI's (otherwise known as Fisher, Clopper-Pearson, etc.), which is what I would be using in your situation (you ran a binomial test, it follows -exactly- a binomial distribution, so you should use a binomial test, and not one based on normal approximations, more or less massaged...).
Binomial CI's are more "conservative" than normal approximations for small n's. That is true, but I do not see that as a problem (after all, more "conservative" means larger CI's which fail to include the true proportion less often than your stated significance, which I would not call a "problem" or failure of the test. It is a problem of the sample size, or its lack of power, which is a well known property of binomial tests (they require higher sample sizes than, say normal tests, for the same power; all you know is that a sample passed, but you do not know by how much: barely of with flying colors. That loss of information requires larger samples to compensate...). This is related to the discrete nature of binomial tests, but as n gets above 50 or 100, this effect disappears.